# How to map type and add a this-based type guards in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typeguards, type-mapping

Suppose there is a interface of arbitrary members like this:

```js
interface A extends Record<string, any[]>{
  // Later used by interface merging
}

//maybe
declare module "./main"{
  interface A{
    func: [arg1:string]
  }
}
```

And I want to map `A` like this, with this-based type guards:

```js
interface Try1<T extends keyof A>{
  [K in keyof A]: (...args: A[K]) => this is Try1<K> 
  // Lots of errors
}
type Try2<T extends keyof A> = {
  [K in keyof A]: (...args: A[K]) => this is Try1<K> 
  // Error: A 'this' type is available only in a non-static member of a class or interface.ts(2526)
}
```

So how can I do it?

### Actual usage:

```js
interface Elements extends Record<string, [any[], any]>{
  // Later used by interface merging
}

interface Elements{
  button: [[text: string], MouseEvent];
}

class ImguiContext<CurrentEv extends keyof Elements>{
  // !!!
  [E in keyof Elements]: (...args: Elements[E][0]) => this is ImguiContext<E>;

  event: Elements[CurrentEv][1];
}


function main(_: ImguiContext){
  if(_.button("Click me")){
    // now `_.event` should be `MouseEvent`
    console.log("clicked at X:", _.event.screenX);
  }
}
```

#### Another possible solution, but failed

```js
let a:string|number = 1;
function aIsNumber(/*no parameter*/)/*: ???*/ {
  return typeof a === "number";
}
```

`???` can be

1. `Assertion functions` like `asserts condition`
2. `Type predicates` like `a is number`

but both failed

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your reply. #51948 is something just like what I meant. The unused `T` is not a typo, and the actual use case is that in the imgui framework, if `_.button(...)` returns true, `_.data` should be `MouseEvent` and `_` should be `_<"button">`

Comment: @jcalz thank you for help and the question has been edited with a more detailed example. The design of imgui requires such thing because we don't have `if let` statement in TS...

Comment: Can I do thing [like this](https://tsplay.dev/Wob0lm) ?

Comment: I don't know what you intend that to be and it's out of scope for the question as asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's apparently a missing feature of TypeScript to allow "`this`" [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) (as originally implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#5906](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/5906)) in [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).  If you try to do it you'll get the error you mentioned.  There's an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#51958](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51948) to support this, but for now it's not officially part of the language.  The issue is listed as "Awaiting more feedback", so if you want to see this happen it couldn't hurt to go there, give it a , and describe why your use case is compelling.

Interestingly, in that issue it is [noted in that issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51948#issuecomment-1362234462) that—despite the error—the code actually does behave as expected.

So one could *possibly* issue [a `//@ts-ignore` comment directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments) to suppress the error, and treat this as an "unsupported feature".  Here's how it might look for your example:

```
interface Elements {
  button: [[text: string], MouseEvent];
  other: [[age: number, isSquishy: boolean], Date]; 
}

type ImguiContext<K extends keyof Elements = keyof Elements> = {
  //@ts-ignore this is usually a bad idea
  [E in keyof Elements]: (...args: Elements[E][0]) => this is ImguiContext<E>;
} & { event: Elements[K][1]; }
    
function main(_: ImguiContext) {
  if (_.button("Click me")) {
    // now `_.event` should be `MouseEvent`
    console.log("clicked at X:", _.event.screenX); // okay
  } else if (_.other(2, false)) {
    console.log("otherThing", _.event.getFullYear()); // okay
  }
}
```

I really wouldn't recommend doing that, though.  The `//@ts-ignore` directive only prevents the error from being displayed; it doesn't fix the underlying problem the compiler has.  Maybe that's fine because the underlying problem is confined to the error reported, or maybe you'll run into weird indirect issues in other parts of your code because of it.  The documentation for the directive says it should be used "*very sparingly*" (emphasis theirs).  So use it at your own risk.

---

Instead I'd be inclined to wrap your context in a version whose type TypeScript can represent without errors.  If, instead of being a mapped type, `ImguiContext` had a `test()` method that accepted the name and args, you could rewrite it as a plain `interface`:

```
interface ImprovedContext<T = unknown> {
  test<E extends keyof Elems>(
    name: E, ...args: Elems[E][0]
  ): this is ImprovedContext<Elems[E][1]> // no ts-ignore needed
  event: T
}
```

If you need to write a helper function to wrap your old context in the new one you can, since that only requires a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) which is less dangerous than `//@ts-ignore`:

```
function improveContext(_: ImguiContext): ImprovedContext {
  return {
    test(n, ...args) { return (_[n] as any)(...args) },
    event: _.event
  }
}
```

And then things still work:

```
function main2(_Orig: ImguiContext) {
  const _ = improveContext(_Orig);
  if (_.test("button", "Click me")) {
    console.log("clicked at X:", _.event.screenX); // okay
  } else if (_.test("other", 2, false)) {
    console.log("otherThing", _.event.getFullYear()); // okay
  }
}
```

Of course it depends on your use case whether it's more feasible to rely on an unsupported feature or to refactor to a version that is supportable.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIBsIFsLgM7IQAekIAJgQEoQID2UZAPHmFKAOYA0yA2nCAE8eAXW78BwgHzIA3gChkyAPRLkAGTiQoyAK54IZZACMByUFvhJkOKOw5yAvnLnnollBmy4wBeYqM6YGC0IABcvDyQJOEsbCDsosgAsrR6EKgAbt7CANwKyLRgABbQ4Tx87BDhIDpYRtDcwHgAygCOOk1FAuFGtLSY-IkAIpoQwo7OcmACAA4oAJJY7B0AwiFRYIwA0oQkuBTIANYQArQwaJg4+MgAvEcnZxde+NJ3fspKAAI+ALTA7CB6Chik1kPpsARgsZgSUCiB0KYAO5wUxQvA6GYzKAQPCQ2HQKD0YyBMxgADkBEBYGQ2LoWCuZAM+R4qDMIHup3OniuPmE4QAFAA6YVwWx4cLc7x4FnCHgABmEAEpbtIQQRQYtlsA1uBiJtUJI8g5kAAyWSELLgCWXKU8LaygCMuWQTmcMB0IAQYGAIWscFA-IA+uFNat1nrle9gOcg4KAkEQvyAEQrdDABCHawQJOKyP5RQqZCAxHIAAGgcFEEtYFLYKKqXQhnqZZSaUy3lL+eQdBAeH6EEF6Fo7GTCDTGYMyE0yAAGqEk9wK1XvIK8AhsbgZ4q8opjRB0PozDGK4USlB+QAmbjwA8QXOyLs9vuYQfD5On6AAFSKHAXyCX1aCpUYAAGI6Og6AAJoQKK-K5vkTiutMcxPFgBBvMyOygByjyStccAELEHC7KQBw7AA-EWy7aOE9rWs8Ph2uMrquLAiALFgWK0FkZA6hsjCfrcuggIcxYgNI7yQCwjCsnq+wEMcnKoXgkj8l2IBwDgErcMKgqiuw4rKTK8rjIoirhGqZgEIsXE8XxeoyZc0qoI6Uj5MuVrIJ+ExyO6nrer6wCcYSWT2SQQYhksYa6iQ5nIDZIUGGF1LvNiYA6FA7LvIoUlgPyIA6SKYqRjSEDpZlyBBjwIDCFOBDiIqQpFQZyoOJwXYeWA4QAd4CE+X5Xo+uyWD+iAF5BgA8mw7CRVqyV5ooT7UoGQlBbZEDJZN03bvk0aVRWuXJvGwQgH+KbjpmOA5gtijdiEz4DkOI5JmO6bHIY05zn+PXgKu64QJuO27oQt5HvtgqHUmH5QH+V7IDe+j3tld29v2r7PdD36-oulaAcBYEQdBsHwbujhAA)